# How to get one day less from the date selected in sql

Tags: sql

How to get one day less from the current date

`to_char(main_table.date_time, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`
I want to get one day reduced from it

Comment: Please add a tag for the type of sql you're working with

Comment: `to_char(main_table.date_time - 1, ...)`?

Comment: Date functions are highly database-specific. Please tag your question with the database that you are using: oracle, postgresql, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Oracle, and if so you can add or deduct the number of days from the existing

```
Select to_char(main_table.date_time - 1, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from main_table
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be5204/4)